# how to fill out the spaces on either side of a DIV

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a div nav bar and I want it to fill out all the space across the width of the page. I have tried using the margin-left and margin-right but it didn't work. Any idea how this is achieved?

This is what I have tried:

```
.nav{
    background-color: #2EC0FE;
    opacity: 0.75;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    height: 100px;
    width: cover;
    margin-top: 500px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Edit:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!--<img src="hksquared.jpg" id="bg" alt="">-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like This?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="nav">a</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    background-color: #2EC0FE;
    opacity: 0.75;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XmZwh/)